# JProfiler shows "unknown" JDBC calls take 40% of the time

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jdbc, jprofiler

I am using JProfiler to view all the JDBC calls in my application that's using Hibernate. It turns out that the top 2 hot spots are "`unknown`" and "`select 1`". Any ideas what they are?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "select 1" is a check to see if the connection is still valid. Can also be "select 1 from dual" or "select 1+1" depending on database used.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Roger Lindsjö's answer, the "unknown" hot spot is a bug that has been fixed in JProfiler 7.0.1.